# How to assign texts to TextViews array through loop?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I have a TextView array in Xamarin which contains 16 TextViews.

I want to loop through that array and set each TextView's text to a random number.

I tried this code but recived errors after pressing the button which starts the loop:

**(Unhandled Exception: System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. occurred)**

**The code:**

```
for(int i = 0; i < textViewArray.Length; i++)
            {
               textViewArray[i].Text = rand.Next(1, 16).ToString();
            }
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You need to narrow down what is null. Use the debugger, set break points and inspect your variables. Most likely one of the indices is null and that is why you are getting an exception.

Comment: either one (or more) elements of `textViewArray` is null, and/or `rand` is null.  Figure out which and fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your `textViewArray[i]` hasn't instantiated to specific objects.So you need to initialize these variables.

You can do like this:

```
int textViewCount = 10;
TextView[] textViewArray = new TextView[textViewCount];
Random rand = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < textViewCount; i++)
 {
    textViewArray[i] = new TextView(this);
    textViewArray[i].Text = rand.Next(1, 16).ToString();

 }
```

And there is a simple demo you can refer to it.

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        //SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        // root layout
        var layout_main = new LinearLayout(this);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams p1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
         LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent
        );
        layout_main.LayoutParameters = p1;
        layout_main.Orientation = Orientation.Vertical;


        // children 
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams param1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MatchParent, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WrapContent, 1f);
        param1.SetMargins(5, 10, 5, 10);
        Random rand = new Random();

        int textViewCount = 10;
        TextView[] textViewArray = new TextView[textViewCount];

        for (int i = 0; i < textViewCount; i++)
        {
            textViewArray[i] = new TextView(this);
            textViewArray[i].LayoutParameters = param1;
            textViewArray[i].SetBackgroundColor(Color.Yellow);
            textViewArray[i].Gravity = GravityFlags.CenterHorizontal;

            textViewArray[i].Text = rand.Next(1, 16).ToString();

            layout_main.AddView(textViewArray[i]);
        }
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(layout_main);
    }
}
```

The result is:

[image]